# How to add Indy components to C++ Builder project?

Tags: c++, delphi, indy

I get undefined errors when I try to add them to an empty project. In Delphi you'd just add a 'uses'. Are there any tutorials on this?

For example, adding:

```
TIdHTTP test*=new TIdHTTP;
```

produces: `Undefined Symbol: TIdHTTP`

Target platform is Win32 Release. I'm using RAD 10 Studio Seattle Version 23.0

[What my tool palette looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWPNk.png)

Comment: How *specifically* are you *trying to add them*, and what *specific* errors are you getting? I start a new VCL Forms Application, drop a TIdHTTP component on the form, and build the project and it works fine, with no errors or warnings, and it generates an executable.

Comment: Dynamically, like 'TIdHTTP test*=new TIdHTTP;'. The error is Undefined Symbol: TIdHTTP

Comment: Then you need to add the proper include files manually. The easiest way? Drop the component on the form, compile to make sure the header files and libraries are correct, and then delete the component from the form and create it manually if you want to do so. (And [edit] your question to be specific and to include the code you're trying to use. Without it, there's no information in your question. We shouldn't have to guess what you're asking or what you're doing.)

Comment: I'd do that, but I don't have them in the Tool Palette

Comment: Which header files do I need to include?

Comment: If you don't have them in the Component Palette, you have something wrong. What OS are you targeting? What type of application? What version of C++ Builder? (Why are you making me play 20 questions, instead of just making a substantial edit to your post and provide sufficient details there for us to use to help you?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C++ equivalent of Delphi's `uses` clause is `#include` statements for C++ header file.

In this case, to use `TIdHTTP` in C++, you need an `#include <IdHTTP.hpp>` statement in your C++ code, and make sure Indy's header files are in a folder in your project's Includes search path.  If you drop a `TIdHTTP` component on a Form/Frame/DataModule at design-time, the IDE will generate the `#include` statement for you.  Otherwise you have to add it manually.

Comment: Thank you. Solved all my problems