# Delphi/C++ Builder TRestClient Mime Boundary bug

Tags: c++, delphi

I'm using C++ Builder 10.3 and I have been having a problem with `TRestClient`. I am sending a `multipart/form-data` RestRequest but the boundary value is incorrect. I have found the following solution:

[Delphi 10 TRestClient Mime Boundary issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60961222/delphi-10-trestclient-mime-boundary-issue/62134165#62134165)

which describes a bug in the `System.Net.Mime.pas` file. The solution is to edit the file and change a value, which I can do.

However, the change has no effect on my project. I have tried copying the file into my project folder, but that won't work because I use Runtime Packages.

I believe I need to re-compile `rtl.bpl` to get the change to register in my project. Can someone please give me advice on how to do this please?

Comment: I'm not sure if you have the right to modify the RTL. I would just use another component.

Comment: You can't recompile `rtl.bpl`. It's not allowed.

Comment: @ Oliver - Can you recommend a component please ? I am using the components which are built into the Builder IDE so I'm assuming you mean a third party component @Ken White - Thanks for your replies. I understand I'm not allowed to modify and then distribute it because of licensing but I don't intend to do that. I just want to get the application  functioning for now.

Comment: You don't understand. :-) You can't build them, because that would mean you would be able to redistribute them if you chose to do so. As you're not allowed to build them at all, you no longer have the option of redistributing them. Also, you can't ask for a component recommendation here according to the [site guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: You can use Indy (as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36902229/how-to-add-indy-components-to-c-builder-project)).

Comment: Thank you both for coming back to me. @Ken White - I see what you mean now. My confusion arose from the fact I have done similar things in the past with previous versions of Builder (there were batch and make files for the very purpose I recall :-)

Comment: @Olivier - Perfect I'll look into that. Thanks !